# MS Access Multiple SELECT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have three tables:

Fields

```
ID | FarmID | FIELD_NUM | Year
```

Farms

```
ID | ClientID
```

Clients

```
ID | CLIENT_NUM
```

I have a simple query to get CLIENT_NUM from the Clients table:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT CLIENT_NUM FROM Clients 
  WHERE ID = (SELECT ClientID FROM Farms WHERE ID = FarmID)) AS CID
FROM Fields 
WHERE Year = 2014 AND FIELD_NUM = '28-2'
```

In SQL Server, this works just fine; however, in Microsoft Access it takes forever.  Is there a better way to run this query?

Comment: What is a relationship between `Client`, `Farms` and `Fields`? `Fields` is not related to any other table in your query

Comment: CLIENT_NUM is in the Clients table. ClientID is in the Farms table and is related to the ID column of Clients.  FarmID is in the Fields table and is related to the ID column of Farms.

Comment: For clarity here, and all future production code, please add table references to your columns (ie, `Farms.ClientId`).  If necessary, assign aliases to tables.  Part of the problem is that subqueries in the `SELECT` portion of a query can just run long - and you're lucky it's only returning one row, or it'd throw.  Probably you actually want a `JOIN` or two, which would help.

Comment: After your update it is not clear where the field `Year` comes from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using sub-queries, try using `JOIN`. Depending on how Access optimizes the query it could help with performance, but also it helps a lot with readability:

```
SELECT Clients.CLIENT_NUM as CID
FROM (Clients INNER JOIN Farms ON Clients.ID = Farms.ClientID)
    INNER JOIN Fields ON Farms.ID = Fields.FarmID
WHERE Fields.Year = 2014 AND Fields.FIELD_NUM = '28-2'
```

Comment: This produces the error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Clients.ID = Farms.ClientID INNER JOIN Fields ON Farms.ID = Fields.FarmID."

Comment: It seems Access requires extra parenthesis in the joins. This would be working in SQL Server, but not in Access. I updated answer, try If it works now